# Understanding tracks in AVAsset

Tags: ios, avasset

I'm attempting to render an audio waveform based on a sound file.  I've found plenty of tutorials showing how to do this, but I haven't found too much documentation covering `AVAsset`.  I've looked over the apple documentation but I find it kind of vague.

I'd really like to understand the basics rather than jumping around.  I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what a track is.  If my asset is a video would I have one track that represents the video and another track that represents the audio?

```
AVAssetTrack * someTrack = [songAsset.tracks objectAtIndex:0];
```

In the code above, is `objectAtIndex:0` representing "an array of format descriptions"?

What am I using `AVAsset` to achieve?  A collection of samples?

Comment: Your question is kind of all over the map. Just what _programming problem_ are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Sorry about that.  If my asset consists of one audio file, do I just have one track or multiple tracks?

Comment: Probably just one, but there is no need to guess - AVAsset gives you the tools to find out.

Answer (score 0):

You can get video tracks of an asset just like below

```
[anAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]
```

That will give you an array. From that you can find out how many video tracks included in your asset file.

Following is the way of getting audio tracks.

```
[anAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio]
```

Just like above you can find out the audio tracks that the particular asset has and access a track like below

```
[[anAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0]
```

In your code what you return is both video and audio tracks.

Comment: Kindly read full question.
He meant to ask what are tracks, what is AVAsset class, how is data modelled in this class? I am also curious to know.